# Saving multiple date ranges simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, simple-form

I have 2 models: vacancy and vacancy_schedule

```
Vacancy has_many :vacancy_schedules
Vacancy_schedule belongs_to :vacancy
```

In my vacancy_schedule I want to save 
vacancy_id, start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time

I've looked a bit into nested forms and I thought about doing it with a nested form:

```
class Vacancy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vacancy_schedueles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vacancy_schedueles
end
```

But how would I display this in my view?

I want to be able to press a + button and keep adding dates underneath each other.

My guess for only adding 1 date to the other model I would have to do something like this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :vacancyscheduele do |t| %>
  <%= t.input :start_date, :as => :date_picker, :label => false%>
  <%= t.input :end_date, :as => :date_picker, :label => false%>
  <%= t.input :end_hour %>
  <%= t.input :end_hour %>
<% end %>
```

But I wouldn't know where to start when I would want to add a + sign and suddenly show a second simple_fields_for where the user can enter a next date.

And when he presses submit it all submits at the same time or when he deletes one of the dates it gets removed correctly.

The end result should be something like this in the vacancy_schedule:

```
Vacancy_id / start_date / end_date    / start_time / end_time
1          /  1/1/2015  / 2/1/2015    / 14:30      / 19:30
1          /  5/1/2015  / 6/1/2015    / 11:30      / 12:30
1          /  10/1/2015 / 11/1/2015   / 16:30      / 19:30
2          /  6/1/2015  / 7/1/2015    / 14:30      / 19:30
etc etc
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code:

Create a file date_format.rb in config/initializers & write the following code:

class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
   def as_date(options = {})
      strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
  end

def as_time(options = {})
    strftime('%I:%M')
  end

end

In the view , write the following code:
     <%= f.simple_fields_for :vacancyscheduele do |t| %>
        <%= t.start_date.as_date %>
     <%= t.end_date.as_date %>
     <%= t.start_hour.as_time %>
     <%= t.end_hour.as_time %>
     <% end %>

Comment: Hi, formatting isnt that important at this point, making it work would be enough :) Thank you

Comment: Check the above code in view. If you want the form field , then write<%= f.text_field :start_date, :value => f.start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>